# Why does my login endpoint in django knox throw "Bad request..." error?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I used files from "https://github.com/Omkar0231/Django-Login-API" with as is. The login request from Postman is resulting in error, "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", while the terminal shows "Bad request...".

The developer of the source code in above git has also explained it in a video, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6d0fiPj0dsA", however, in video everything seems to be working as expected.

Whatever I understood from Googling, I thought that a bearer token is to be included in the login request as header. But I don't know where to find the bearer token in my Django app. However, in the video, the original author/developer did not include any such header token for the login request from Postman.

Please help me figure out the issue.

Comment: did you create an object?

Comment: Yes Tanveer, I created a user in the user table. The credentials required to login for that created user are email and password. Despite of entering correct credentials I am getting this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.